# Not able to run juju bootstrap : ERROR You are not allowed to start up this node

Tags: juju, maas

Trying to install MaaS server with juju using 12.10 ubuntu. MaaS was well installed with separate dhcp/dns server. Created then:
 ~/.juju/environments.yaml with the following content:

```
juju: environments environments:   maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://myMaaSIpAddress'
    maas-oauth: '${maas-api-key}'
    admin-secret: 'nothing'
```

then run ssh-keygen

After adding the Mac address of node01 in maas. I noticed that wake on lan works and the new node being booted and installed buuuuut..Once trying to create my juju env with:

```
juju bootstrap
```

it returns:

```
 590 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: ppa type: maas)...
    005 ERROR Failed to launch machine /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-0516f9b8-825d-11e2-90af-0050561dd02a/; attempting to release.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/maas/launch.py", line 49, in start_machine
        instance_uri, series, cloud_init.render())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/maas/maas.py", line 82, in _process_error
        raise ProviderError(error.response)
    ProviderError: You are not allowed to start up this node.
    133 ERROR You are not allowed to start up this node.
```

It seems as authentication process goes wrong. However the MAASKey was copied from the MAAS GUI once generated new one. The node is being changing its status to ready but could not bootstrap juju???? ANY IDEA???

Answer (score 2):

Basically here tow fundamentals reasons for that error:

1. The node is not ready when generating the ssh key.
2. Zookeeper is not being runinng it s agent in the node so does not pass the ssh key even the node started form maas.

if you have other experiences with this. Please share !!!